# How to add horizontal line with expression or with stored procedure in SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportingservices-2005

This is my first time using SSRS and I have a problem when I want to **add a horizontal line just above the words I marked (see picture)**. I am trying to make a financial report using SSRS Report Builder. I have an idea using expression but I don't know what kind of code I should enter. Please help me if you understand this.

[image]

Comment: probably need to see the report in design view but typically, if you want a line at the end of a group, you can just set the bottom border of the last row in the group to whatever you want. If you want a line between objects (say between 2 distinct tables, then you can just add a line (right-click the design surface and then do "Insert --> Line" and position to suit your needs.

Comment: do you have to use an expression for the horizontal line? because there is only one line that I want to display according to what is drawn, not in each group @AlanSchofield

Comment: Is the Red line always above the non-operating Gains (losses) section? If it is, then just add a top red border for that title / group header line. No need for any expression of any sort.

Comment: That's right, just above that. what are the steps to do that? @Harry

Comment: Like I said in my comment, you simply need to add a Boarder with a bigger width and red color. Share your design view of this report to your question